# ¿Cómo hago que el bot detecte 2 respuestas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

¿Como hago que el bot detecte si y no?

Aquí esta el código:

```
async def banco(ctx):
    await ctx.send('¿Quieres iniciar un robo al banco?')
    await ctx.send('Di Si o No')
    def check(m):
            return m.content == 'si'

    await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=10)
    msg = await ctx.send('Iniciando atraco')

    def check(m):
            return m.content == 'no'

    await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=10)
    msg = await ctx.send('qlo')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estas confundiendo conceptos, el objetivo de wait_for es esperar hasta que la función `check` retorne True(o si se termina el timeout si se le establecio). Es decir no tiene como objetivo responder nada sino solo esperar. Esa misma función retorna el objeto asociado el evento, en este caso al mensaje que puede ser usado para enviar la respuesta que se desea basado en el contenido:

```
async def banco(ctx):
    await ctx.send("¿Quieres iniciar un robo al banco?")
    await ctx.send("Di Si o No")

    def check(m):
        return m.content in ("si", "no")

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

    await ctx.send("Iniciando atraco" if msg.content == "si" else "qlo")
```

Comment: Oye bro, la verdad es que no lo habia testeadp bien, ya que solo habia checado el "si" pero , ahora que lo cheque , el "no" no funcionaba, le hice un arreglo y ahora funciona el "qlo" pero el "Iniciando atraco" ya no lo detecta

Comment: @RobertoPascal yo lo he testeado y a mi me funciona correctamente

Comment: Voy a revisar eso

Comment: Oye amigo, ya funciono, eran las comillas, pero me gustaría saber como editar el segundo mensaje, el de "qlo", editarlo con msg.edit